# How do I develop and distribute a Ruby CLI app with a backing database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, distribution

I'm writing a command line program that maintains state in a database. Are there any templates for setting up an app folder structure similar to Rails? I.e. have infrastructure for:

- Having all files in lib, app, etc directories auto-required in all of those files
- Having multiple database environments like dev, test, prod
- Having Rake tasks for runnning tests in a test database

So, this is essentially a Rails layout but without anything to do with serving web-pages.

Once I have this kind of app, I want to distribute it via a gem, but have it initialize a database in the user's home directory when installed, maybe in `~/.myapp`.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Is this hypothetical app for single or multiple users on a machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a gem based application you could look into this guys development here:
http://www.acmesprockets.com/node/24

Comment: this url link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You could just forgo Rails and using stock ruby with [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html) and ActiveRecord or [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Yes, those are great. But they offer nothing in the way of separating development/testing/prod environment and don't help with packaging.

Comment: So why not just add Rake into the mix, then? I suppose it wouldn't be too hard to hack Rails to generate text to display on the console instead of HTML in a browser. I've never tried, but I assume you would just have to replace HTTP front end with something custom.